# Not able to use virtualType as Action constructor argument

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, configuration, di, virtualtype

In short I seem unable to use a virtualType I created as an argument in my Action's contructor but everything works fine when using a concrete class instead.

Index.php (my action):

```
namespace Unit1\CustomConfig\Controller\Test;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends Action{
    private $customConfig;

    public function __construct(Context $context, \Unit1\CustomConfig\Model\Config $customConfig){
        $this->customConfig = $customConfig;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }
}
```

My di.xml (Unit1/CustomConfig/etc/di.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager:etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Unit1\CustomConfig\Model\Config" type="Magento\Framework\Config\Data">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="reader" xsi:type="object">Unit1\CustomConfig\Model\Config\Reader</argument>
            <argument name="cacheId" xsi:type="string">welcome_messages</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    .......
</config>
```

I get the error:

> main.CRITICAL: **Class Unit1\CustomConfig\Model\Config does not exist**
>
> Class Unit1\CustomConfig\Controller\Test\Index\Interceptor generation
>   error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the
>   'generated' directory permission is read-only. If --- after running
>   the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated'
>   directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not
>   generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the
>   signature of the related construct method, only. [ ] [ ]

The error has nothing to do with file permissions (I checked and confirmed - it generates all the other files and folders - just not this interceptor as it cannot find the Model\Config class).

The thing is I am really confused on why it cannot find the virtualType or am I understanding the virtual type wrong?

This is part of an excercise in Magento U and the exercise initially used a concrete class for Model\Config along with a type (instead of virtualType) in the di.xml. I saw that the concrete class didn't really do much so based on my understanding of virtualType I wanted to confirm that I could simply replace it. But it's not so. How come? This was the original excercise solution which works:

Config.php:

```
namespace Unit1\CustomConfig\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Config\ReaderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Config\CacheInterface;

class Config extends \Magento\Framework\Config\Data {
    public function __construct(ReaderInterface $reader, CacheInterface $cache, $cacheId = ''){
        parent::__construct($reader, $cache, $cacheId);
    }
}
```

and the corresponding type in the di.xml:

```
<type name="Unit1\CustomConfig\Model\Config">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="reader" xsi:type="object">Unit1\CustomConfig\Model\Config\Reader</argument>
        <argument name="cacheId" xsi:type="string">welcome_messages</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

That is all that has changed - Instead of a concrete class and a type in di.xml I just turned it into a virtual type. And once I change those back they work perfectly. But the virtualType does not work. Can someone explain to my why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to magento docs:

> Virtual types are a way to inject different dependencies into existing PHP classes without affecting other classes and without having to create a new class file. Virtual types can only be referenced in by argument overrides in a element within di.xml files, never in source code. They can't be extended and they can't be references as dependencies in a classes constructor. ([magento glossary](https://glossary.magento.com/virtual-type/))

This is not the proper use. What you are trying to do is to use `virtualType` just like an interface when in fact those are two different concepts. `virtualTypes` are meant for `di.xml` manipulation only. They are usefull if you have `Unit1\CustomConfig\Model\Config` used in two or more classes as a dependency but `ClassA` needs to use `Unit1\CustomConfig\Model\Config` but replace one of its constructor arguments with a different value (for simple types) or a subclass (for classes).

Check [this answer](http://Unit1%5CCustomConfig%5CModel%5CConfig) for more clarification.

Comment: Great. Thank you for the definition. It makes sense now.
P.S. the second link doesn't work.